# Uso de operator()

Tags: c++, estructuras

estoy buscando cómo obtener el valor de una **TextLine** en el motor **Esenthel**.
El único problema por el momento es que no entiendo como puedo utilizar el siguiente código para que me devuelva el texto introducido.

```
#define C const

const_mem_addr struct TextLine : GuiObj
{
    C Str&  operator()()C
    {
       return _text;
    }
    
    private:
       Str _text;
}
```

mi código:

```
TextLine text_line;

void AddMessage()
{
    chat.New(/*Aquí debería utilizar la variable de tipo C Str con el texto de la TextLine*/);
}
```

Gracias

Comment: C Str&  operator()()C {return _text      ;}       //Esta es tal cual la linea de código del Engine Esenthel

Comment: #define C const //C es de const

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La estructura `TextLine` define un

```
const Str &operator()() const
```

por lo que no tienes mas que llamarlo:

```
TextLine text_line;

void AddMessage( ) {
    chat.New( text_line( ) );
}
```

Comment: Y yo intentando añadir código... Muchas gracias